# Type mismatch error while selecting multiple rows while running a for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel table prepared as a blank format on the active sheet.

I am trying to create a macro which will copy this blank format and insert it at the top of the sheet. The blank format is 30 rows long.

So, I need to select and copy 30 rows, before inserting at the top of the sheet. Logic is to search for the word "blank" and start selecting from that row to **row+29**

Following is my code:

```
Sub Copy_Blank_Format()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rg As Range
    
    Worksheets("abc").Select
    For i = 1 To 500
        If (InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i), "BLANK", vbTextCompare)) Then
            Rows("i:(i+29)").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Rows("2").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

It is giving me a type mismatch error on the `Rows("i:(i+29)").Select` line.

Similar format works with numbers Eg: `Rows("3:5").Select`
Don't know why it is giving an error.

Can someone advice?

Comment: `Rows(i & ":" & i+29)`. Or `Rows(i).Resize(30)`.